# SQL Guide Plan not being used?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, plan-guides

I'm try to get force Parameterization on a simple adhoc SQL query.As explained in this article https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/fixing-cache-bloat-problems-with-guide-plans-and-forced-parameterization/

But even trying to do this with the simplest query I cant get it to work

```
CREATE TABLE fruit
(
 id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY(id)
,title VARCHAR(150)
)
INSERT INTO fruit VALUES ( 1, 'Apple') , ( 2, 'Banana'), ( 3, 'Orange'), ( 4, 'Pear')

DECLARE @params nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @stmt nvarchar(max);
EXEC sp_get_query_template N'SELECT title FROM fruit WHERE id = 4',@stmt OUTPUT, @params OUTPUT;

--SELECT @params
EXEC sp_create_plan_guide 
    N'fruitGuide', 
    @stmt, 
    N'TEMPLATE', 
    NULL, 
    @params, 
    N'OPTION(PARAMETERIZATION FORCED)';
GO

SELECT title FROM fruit WHERE id = 1
```

Plan XML:

Shows a compile and doesn't use the plan guide, is there something i'm missing here? Where am i going wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ShowPlanXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.5" Build="13.0.1601.5" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan">
  <BatchSequence>
    <Batch>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="1" StatementEstRows="1" StatementId="1" StatementOptmLevel="TRIVIAL" CardinalityEstimationModelVersion="130" StatementSubTreeCost="0.0032831" StatementText="select title from fruit where id = @0" StatementType="SELECT" QueryHash="0xC02C3539A6CB7253" QueryPlanHash="0x257948D9E7B502E7" RetrievedFromCache="true" SecurityPolicyApplied="false">
          <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" />
          <QueryPlan DegreeOfParallelism="1" CachedPlanSize="16" CompileTime="1" CompileCPU="1" CompileMemory="104">
            <MemoryGrantInfo SerialRequiredMemory="0" SerialDesiredMemory="0" />
            <OptimizerHardwareDependentProperties EstimatedAvailableMemoryGrant="256000" EstimatedPagesCached="64000" EstimatedAvailableDegreeOfParallelism="2" />
            <RelOp AvgRowSize="86" EstimateCPU="0.0001581" EstimateIO="0.003125" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Seek" NodeId="0" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Seek" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0032831" TableCardinality="4">
              <OutputList>
                <ColumnReference Database="[DV]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[fruit]" Column="title" />
              </OutputList>
              <RunTimeInformation>
                <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="1" ActualRowsRead="1" Batches="0" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" ActualExecutionMode="Row" ActualElapsedms="0" ActualCPUms="0" ActualScans="0" ActualLogicalReads="2" ActualPhysicalReads="0" ActualReadAheads="0" ActualLobLogicalReads="0" ActualLobPhysicalReads="0" ActualLobReadAheads="0" />
              </RunTimeInformation>
              <IndexScan Ordered="true" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="false" ForceSeek="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false" Storage="RowStore">
                <DefinedValues>
                  <DefinedValue>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[DV]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[fruit]" Column="title" />
                  </DefinedValue>
                </DefinedValues>
                <Object Database="[DV]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[fruit]" Index="[PK__fruit__3213E83F1B7D3288]" IndexKind="Clustered" Storage="RowStore" />
                <SeekPredicates>
                  <SeekPredicateNew>
                    <SeekKeys>
                      <Prefix ScanType="EQ">
                        <RangeColumns>
                          <ColumnReference Database="[DV]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[fruit]" Column="id" />
                        </RangeColumns>
                        <RangeExpressions>
                          <ScalarOperator ScalarString="CONVERT_IMPLICIT(bigint,[@0],0)">
                            <Convert DataType="bigint" Style="0" Implicit="true">
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Identifier>
                                  <ColumnReference Column="@0" />
                                </Identifier>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </Convert>
                          </ScalarOperator>
                        </RangeExpressions>
                      </Prefix>
                    </SeekKeys>
                  </SeekPredicateNew>
                </SeekPredicates>
              </IndexScan>
            </RelOp>
            <ParameterList>
              <ColumnReference Column="@0" ParameterCompiledValue="(1)" ParameterRuntimeValue="(1)" />
            </ParameterList>
          </QueryPlan>
        </StmtSimple>
      </Statements>
    </Batch>
  </BatchSequence>
</ShowPlanXML>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Your plan guide *is being applied*, and the query *is being forced parameterized*.

Unfortunately, this is not so easy to see in your particular situation, for a couple of reasons:

---

### Reason 1: Post-execution plans do not show plan guide properties

A **quick and reliable way** to see that your query is using the plan guide is to request a **pre-execution** (estimated) plan.

So, *without running the query*, the execution plan shown in SSMS will have a root node with two extra properties (compared with the plan provided in the question):

[image: Extra properties]

These properties **do not appear** in post-execution plans, nor in prepared cached plans.

**Side note**

In the *post-execution* (actual) plan you provided, the only (undocumented) indication that parameterization was *forced* is that the first parameter marker is `@0` in the Seek tooltip:

[image: @0]

Without the plan guide, your test query still qualifies for *simple* parameterization, but the parameter marker in the tooltip is `@1`:

[image: @1]

### Reason 2: You have `optimize for ad hoc workloads` enabled

With this configuration option enabled, the first time you run the adhoc query, no plan is cached, just a plan stub.

You would need to **run the query twice** to see the plan stub populated.

There still won't be a full plan (just a root `SELECT` node) but this node will have the `TemplatePlanGuideDB` and `TemplatePlanGuideName` properties populated:

[image: Stub properties]

Notice also that the `ParameterizedPlanHandle` property points to the plan handle of the fully parameterized (prepared) query plan in cache. The prepared plan **does not** contain the extra plan guide properties, as mentioned previously.

Without the `adhoc` option, the adhoc compiled plan will show the important plan guide properties.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you getting the plan from?  Can you try to retrieve the plan from cache and you should see the guide.

```
select st.*,st1.*,cp.* from sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(cp.plan_handle) st 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cp.plan_handle) st1
where cp.objtype='Adhoc'
```

Comment: query plan is null:  NULL NULL 0 NULL 13 NULL NULL 0 SELECT title FROM fruit WHERE id = 1 11437 1 1 128 0x00000095AE80E040 Compiled Plan Stub Adhoc 0x06000D009A7B9605F0F380AE9500000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 2 NULL ..Using an adhoc plan rather than plan guide

Comment: Keeps ending up as adhoc in cache with no query plan